# Table layout with div

Tags: css, html

I have a problem that I cannot resolve, so if is anyone who can help me, appreciate:

```
________________________________________________________________________________
|       body                                                                    |
|                                                                               |
| ___________   _______________________________________________________________ |
| |          | |                                                               ||           
| |  div B   | |                                                               ||
| |          | |                                                               ||
| |__________| |                                                               ||
|              |     div C                                                     ||
|              |                                                               ||
|              |                                                               ||
|              |                                                               ||
|              |                                                               ||
|              |                                                               ||
|              |                                                               ||
|              |_______________________________________________________________||
|_______________________________________________________________________________|
```

here is my code for this:

```
<body>
...
<div style="float: left;">...</div>
<div style="float: left;">...</div>
...
</body>
```

The problem is that anytime when I put in `div C` text that is more wide - as quantity - than `div C` (look in drawn outline), the `div C` changes its position under `div B`, on the whole `body` width.

So, can anybody tell me how to make `div C` not change its position, without specifying any size value (I mean numerical values)?

Thanks!

N.B. I tried to put `div B` and `div C` in a `display:block` or `display:inline-block` *div*, but without any results

Comment: put them in a div with > display: inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [negative margins](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins) or `display: table/table-cell`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:  width fix

If your setting the width of both of them with percentage say 10% and 90% .. you can get rid of this problem by using `overflow:hidden|scroll|auto` on the `div C`

Solution 2: Position Fix

make the parent's `position:relative` and the `div C` css setting

```
.divC{
position:absolute
top:0
right:0
}
```

Comment: I put the overflow:auto to *div C*, and now works fine, even if I don't specify the widths. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified widths to div B and div C ? if not then,
 try this

```
.divB, .divC{ width:50%;}
```

If you don't specify widths to the divs, then the divs will adjust according to the content inside them.